# edit maximum length of column to break the line in vscode format on save

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use format on save in `vscode` and I want to say `vscode` not to break line in column 80.
These setting did not work for me.

```
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 120,
"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn"
```

what is the correct setting in `setting.json`?

**Edit**:
based on Brett answer, Is it possible to edit the setting for example autopep8 for python?

I am using C/C++ Microsoft extension the latest version.
also python Microsoft extension.

Comment: See https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#configuration for how to configure autopep8.

Answer (score 4):

In your `settings.json`, you can pass arguments to autopep8 and also define the maximum column width:

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=200"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting is going to be tool-specific depending on which formatter you chose to set up using the Python extension (e.g. autopep8 will have its own setting, black has its own setting, etc.).